# Get percentage of positive numbers in this panda series

Tags: pandas, series

I have a panda series that looks like this;

```
0     -10.93
1      -9.18
2      -6.87
3      7.90
4      9.18
5      6.87
6      9.12
7      9.12
8      8.75
9      7.75
```

I would like to get the percentage of positive numbers in this series. In this case, the answer should be 70%.

I am using python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
In [381]: s.ge(0).sum() / len(s.index) * 100.
Out[381]: 70.0
```

Or

```
In [383]: 100. * (s >= 0).sum() / len(s.index)
Out[383]: 70.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `mean` of boolean mask:

```
a = s.gt(0).mean() * 100

a = (np.sign(s) == 1).mean() * 100
```

---

```
print (a)
70.0
```

If want also all negative, positive and zero values is possible use [`numpy.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
print (s)
0   -10.93
1    -9.18
2    -6.87
3     7.90
4     9.18
5     6.87
6     9.12
7     9.12
8     8.75
9     0.00 <- changed last value to 0
Name: a, dtype: float64

b = np.sign(s).value_counts(normalize=True).rename({0:'zero', 1:'pos', -1:'neg'})
print (b)
pos     0.6
neg     0.3
zero    0.1
Name: a, dtype: float64
```